# renovate config issues with labels

Tags: renovate

Im trying to configure renovate to label things and test various configs, but struggling to get a results im happy with.

My current renovate.json file is:

```
{
   "$schema":"https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
   "extends":[
      "config:base",
      ":rebaseStalePrs"
   ],
    "ignorePaths":[
       "**/ruby/**"
   ],
   "labels":[
      "renovatebot"
   ],
   "packageRules":[
      {
         "matchLanguages":[
            "python"
         ],
         "labels":[
            "python-dependencies"
         ]
      },
      {
         "matchLanguages":[
            "ruby"
         ],
         "labels": [
             "ruby-dependency"
         ]
      },
      {
         "datasources":[
            "docker"
         ],
         "addLabels": [
            "docker-dependency"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

running this in a repo that has the following files:

```
root
- Gemfile
- Dockerfile
- requirements.txt
ruby
  - Gemfile
```

[image: PR from renovate]

But im confused why:

- matchLanguages python works for some but not all the python updates that are in the same requirements.txt ? (flask and black have a renovate label??? )
- matchLanguages ruby isnt working at all (still using the default label)
- ive tried multiple attempts to get docker to label including matchManagers / MatchLanguages etc bit it just goes all out and removes the default and doesnt add a new one?!

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider:

- Renovate applies labels only at creation time and do not change them later
- If using `labels`, the latest wins. Therefore if one of the first two rules match only their label is getting applied.
- Should you wish that the labels are combined instead of overwritten use `addLabels`

Comment: 1. Can you point me to the renovate documentation where renovate only applies labels at creation time and does not change them later?

2. Do you have a suggestion for how to adjust the labels when the PR is edited?  I can probably write a github action to do this, but I'm curious if there's a better way...